# foreach $key=>$value to set ZF form values / OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I currently have the following code in a ZF application, to set the values of a Form based on a rowset retrieved from a Db-Table.

```
 $form->forename->setValue($footerContactDetails->forename);
 $form->surname->setValue($footerContactDetails->surname);
 $form->telephone->setValue($footerContactDetails->telephone);
 $form->mobile->setValue($footerContactDetails->mobile);
 $form->fax->setValue($footerContactDetails->fax);
 $form->email->setValue($footerContactDetails->emailAddress);
 $form->address1->setValue($footerContactDetails->address1);
 $form->address2->setValue($footerContactDetails->address2);
 $form->address3->setValue($footerContactDetails->address3);
 $form->townCity->setValue($footerContactDetails->townCity);
 $form->region->setValue($footerContactDetails->region);
```

As the object element names from the rowset match the form elements, what I'd like to do is the following:

```
  foreach ($footerContactDetails as $key=>$value) {
       $form->$key->setValue($value);
  }
```

However this provides the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setValue() on a non-object
```

I expect this question is more related to OOP PHP in general and not the just ZF.

So how can I set these form values using a foreach?

Many thanks

Comment: Your foreach loop looks good - there is probably a property in your footerContactDetails object that's not in the form object.

Comment: `setValue` is predefined function of The `ReflectionProperty class` that reports information about a classes properties. first check your array using `var_dump($footerContactDetails)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `foreach` is fine, but the names dont match:

```
$form->email->setValue($footerContactDetails->emailAddress);
```

So, when iterating over `$footerContactDetails`, your code will eventually try to

```
$form->emailAddress->setValue()
```

but since there is no element of that name in the Zend_Form (it's called email instead), you'll get the error. So change it accordingly and it will work.

On a sidenote, `Zend_Form` has a method for bulk setting:

```
$form->populate((array) $footerContactDetails);
```

It expects an array though, hence the typecast.

Comment: Gordon - this has solved it, thanks! The Bulk setting for Zend_Form looks interesting, and I'll certainly be using this in future. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach($footerContactDetails as $key=>$value){
    $form->{$key}->setValue($value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreach over object variables takes all variables. That means primitive types too. Since primitive type is not an object, you cannot call method on it.

I suggest you use `is_object()` to check if variable is an object before calling a method, or maybe even think of a different approach.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try something like this?

```
foreach ($footerContactDetails as $key=>$value) {
       $form->${$key}->setValue($value);
  }
```

Comment: wouldnt this evaluate to `$form->$region->setValue()`?